# WD Game Drive USB Device at 100% usage and parameter incorrect error

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

So I have a 2TB WD Black USB External HDD and the drive is unable to be accessed and is causing system instability. It is also maxed out at 100% usage with the response time at 0 and spikes to ~1450 and then drops back down to 0. Not sure what to do to get the data back intact or if it is failing. Can't get any CHKDSK readouts either, just a blinking cursor. If it were empty I'd try reformatting it but it isn't empty so I am not sure what to try or do next. Thanks.

The Error in Windows Explorer:

[image: The Error in Windows Explorer]

The Disk usage as in Task Manager:

[image: The Disk usage as in Task Manager]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can't get any CHKDSK readouts either, just a blinking cursor.

The first error is clear. Together with the fact that CHKDSK will not run means the drive has a hardware error.

Try attaching to a different computer and see if it opens in Windows Explorer. Most likely not.

If the data is important to you, take it to a local recovery agency. If the data is important, do not try do it yourself tools first.

Comment: I figured as much, could likely be the cable because I've seen them go bad before. Thank you!